# Is there any downside to using <embed> with Flash content?

Tags: html, css, html5, flash, embed

I've recently learned that HTML5 now officially supports the `<embed>` tag. With that in mind, is there any reason not to just use it to embed Flash content into HTML5? Would there be any browser issues or concerns if I did this?

I'm aware of SWFObject, but I'm trying to find a really simple and neat solution that doesn't rely on JavaScript.

Thanks.

Edit: My only concerns are: FF3, FF4, IE7, IE8, IE9, Chrome and Safari. Mobile users are not a consideration and I'm not streaming any video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your biggest issue will be with users on iPhone/iPad devices as flash doesn't work for them at all.  It also depends on what you are trying to do. If you don't care about mobile platforms then you are most likely fine.

If you do plan on having mobile users then you need to support non-flash solutions.  Also, if you plan on displaying video through your flash player then that is a whole new bag of worms because different devices support different video formats and sizes and you will need to accommodate them all.

Comment: No, I'm not caring about mobile platforms and I'm not streaming any video.

Answer (score 1):

Not every browser supports Flash, for example on the iPhone. Or users may have a browser extension installed that blocks Flash. If you're using Flash to do something important then you need to think what those users will do if the Flash component doesn't work for them.